# Null Pointer Exception upon referencing variable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to reference a variable in a method in my class and keep running into a NullPointerException. I know it is happening at the variable pbook when it is referenced from the addPerson method. Why is this happening and how could I go about fixing it?

```
public class Phonebook <T> {

  private LinkedList<T> pbook;

  public T findPerson(T person) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pbook.size(); i++) {
      if (pbook.get(i).equals(person)) {
        return person;
      }
      else
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void addPerson(T person) {
    pbook.addFirst(person);
  }

  public void deletePerson(T person) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pbook.size(); i++) {
      if (pbook.get(i).equals(person)) {
        pbook.remove(i);
      }
      else
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
  }


  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
     Phonebook<Integer> sspb = new Phonebook<Integer>();
     Phonebook<String> idpb = new Phonebook<String>();
     sspb.addPerson(1234567890);
     idpb.addPerson("Bob");

    }
    catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that while in some languages `LinkedList<T> pbook;` *does* create a new object, in Java it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add a constructor to instantiate your `LinkedList`:

```java
public Phonebook() {
    pbook = new LinkedList<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
private LinkedList<T> pbook;
```

To:

```
private LinkedList<T> pbook = new LinkedList<T>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`private LinkedList<T> pbook;`  You don't create a list.

Try this.

```
private LinkedList<T> pbook = new LinkedList<T>()
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can define a constructor e.g. like this.

```
public Phonebook(LinkedList<T> pbook){
     this.pbook = pbook;
}
```

Then the calling code will have to set the
`pbook` when instantiating the Phonebook.

2) You can initialize `pbook` where you declare it.

`private LinkedList<T> pbook = new LinkedList<T>();`